# Combobox inside a listbox which itself inside a TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox, tabcontrol

I've got stuck in this situation, even my best friend "Google" is not helpful. 
I have nine TabItems. I am able to display data. This is my screen.

[image]
Here is my approach :

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItem">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="450" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Width="250" Text="{Binding Path=HmiText}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="28" Margin="10,10,0,0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Calibri" FontWeight="Bold" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <ComboBox Width="115" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxSourceItem}" DisplayMemberPath="OptionsText"
                            SelectedValuePath="OptionsValue" SelectedValue="{Binding DefaultValue}" Height="23" Margin="10,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<TabControl  Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TabStripPlacement="Top"  VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#005399" Background="White">
    <TabItem Header="Unit Configuration" Width="auto">
        <ListBox Name="UnitConfigurationlist" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding UnitConfigurationItemSource}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItem}" >
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Programmable Features" Selector.IsSelected="True" Width="auto">
        <ListBox Name="list" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedProgrammableFeature}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItem}" >
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Main Menu Configuration" Width="auto" >
        <ListBox Name="MainMenuConfigurationlist" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MainMenuConfigurationItemSource}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItem}" >
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Cycle Sentry Setup" Width="auto">
        <ListBox Name="CycleSentrySetuplist" Margin="5" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding CycleSentrySetuplistItemSource}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListItem}" >
        </ListBox>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Language Setup" Width="auto">
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Here is my view model :

```
public class UnitConfigurationViewModel : ViewModelBase2
{
    private IOptiSetPlusService optiSetPlusService;

    public ObservableCollection<ProgrammableFeatures> ProgrammableFeaturesItemSource
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ProgrammableFeatures> UnitConfigurationItemSource
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public UnitConfigurationViewModel(IOptiSetPlusService os)
    {
        optiSetPlusService = os;
        InitializeUnitConfiguration();
    }

    void InitializeUnitConfiguration()
    {
        GetControlDependencyID();
        //here I am reading the xml file and filling the collection.
        this.ProgrammableFeaturesItemSource = GetCurrentProgrammableFeaturesItemSource(optiSetPlusService.GetProgrammableFeaturesList(ControlDependency.ControlDependencyId.ToString(), "programmableFeatures"));
        this.UnitConfigurationItemSource = GetCurrentProgrammableFeaturesItemSource(optiSetPlusService.GetProgrammableFeaturesList(ControlDependency.ControlDependencyId.ToString(), "unitConfiguration"));
    }
}
```

and finally here is my model:

```
public class ProgrammableFeatures
{
    string toolTip;
    public string ToolTip
    {
        get
        {
            return toolTip;
        }
        set
        {
            toolTip = value;
        }
    }
    string hmiText;
    public string HmiText
    {
        get
        {
            return hmiText;
        }
        set
        {
            hmiText = value;
        }
    }

    string defaultValue;
    public string DefaultValue
    {
        get
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        set
        {
            defaultValue = value;
        }
    }

//this collection will be shown in combobox.
    ObservableCollection<GdtAvailableOptions> comboBoxSourceItem;
    public ObservableCollection<GdtAvailableOptions> ComboBoxSourceItem
    {
        get
        {
            return comboBoxSourceItem;
        }
        set
        {
            comboBoxSourceItem = value;
        }
    }
}

public class GdtAvailableOptions
{
    private string optionsValue;
    public string OptionsValue
    {
        get
        {
            return optionsValue;
        }
        set
        {
            optionsValue = value;
        }
    }

    private string optionsText;
    public string OptionsText
    {
        get
        {
            return optionsText;
        }
        set
        {
            optionsText = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is once the combo-box selection changed, it should affect some other parameters across all of the tabs(ex: rail option should be enabled). I don't how to do this. Please guide me. even any link provided will be also helpful.

Comment: You've bound the SelecctedValue to DefaultValue, so each time the property is changed, do whatever you need to.

Comment: @RodrigoSilva: I don't get it. Could you please explain briefly.

Comment: <DataTemplate x:Key="ListItem" x:shared="false">

Answer (score 0):

```
<ComboBox Width="115" ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxSourceItem}" DisplayMemberPath="OptionsText"
                            SelectedValuePath="OptionsValue" SelectedValue="{Binding DefaultValue}" Height="23" Margin="10,5,0,5" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

You should have a public property for DefaultValue in UnitConfigurationViewModel
When it is changed you should have a call to the set
In the set manipulate what you need to

You may have a problem with that one property shared by several collections
And see the comment from dev hedgehog

Comment: Actually DefaultValue is the property of ProgrammableFeatures class, which is shown in combobox as default value(first time). I also tried as u suggested, but its not working. Do you have any link to share which is related to this problem.

Comment: No DefaultValue is not a property of ProgrammableFeatures class that you posted.  Please post your try of what you think I suggested.

Comment: I've updated the actual ProgrammableFeatures class.There are many other properties too including DefaultValue. Reason for this property is to show default data in the combobox when user clicks first time.

Comment: If DefaultValue binding is working then do you other stuff in set.